# How to clone Raspberry Pi SD Card on Windows, Linux, and macOS?

Tags: sd-card, image, backup, restore

I want to make a back up of my raspberry pi because I have done a lot of work and repeating the process would take a lot of time. How does one go about making an image of a Raspberry Pi SD card for the following operating systems:

- Windows
- Linux
- macOS

A step by step guide would be very helpful!

Comment: On Windows i am using WinDisk32 https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/ and on Linux `cat /dev/mmcblk0 > /rpi.bin`

Comment: There are literally hundreds of posts on this site. These offer many different methods. You could start with the official Foundation [Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/filesystem/backup.md)

Comment: Can't add an answer but for windows the best tool for cloning an SD card is Balena Etcher

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recently had to make a backup image for my `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B` and found an incredibly helpful guide from [Beebom](https://web.archive.org/web/20170119125519/http://beebom.com/).

The guide outlines the process for **cloning** and **restoring** a Pi SD image for all three operating systems. (Windows - Linux - MacOS). For this  detailed and helpful guide visit:

[How to Clone Raspberry Pi SD Card on Windows, Linux and macOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170123034244/http://beebom.com/how-clone-raspberry-pi-sd-card-windows-linux-macos/)

Answer (score 25):

On Linux or OSX I use `dd` to make a backup from SD card. Reverse `if` and `of` (i.e. to where they point - source and destination) afterwards to restore, but be careful not to restore to a wrong disk. It will be destroyed without a warning!!!

First use `fdisk` to get the device id of you SD card (check the size)

```
fdisk -l
```

then I use dd to make a diskimage (change /dev/sdb with what you found with fdisk -l):

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=image1-`date +%d%m%y`.img
```

or this to make a compressed imag:

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb | gzip > image1-`date +%d%m%y`.img.gz
```

on OSX find device with:

```
diskutil list
```

then `dd` with something like `if=/dev/rdisk1` (the '`r`' in `rdisk1` stands for raw which is faster)

On OSX you can also use 'Disk Utility'

by making a crontab like this it will give you a status every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/pkill -USR1 -x dd
```

Comment: For me, on OSX, `-USR1` caused dd to die .. `-INFO` worked as expected - Just the same, I have given this my vote for correct answer - thanks for sharing !

Comment: `dd` will also respond to ^T to provide status while its running.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a backup tool for Raspberries called [raspiBackup](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/backup). If you restore this backup on a different SD card you're actually cloning your Raspberry.

Comment: I have no clue why the link doesn't work for you. The URL is valid. You can visit https://raspibackup.linux-tips-and-tricks.de to get a quick overview about raspiBackup. Next I suggest to use your favourite search engine and search for raspiBackup. You'll get a lot of hits :-)

Comment: It does now. I've deleted my comment.